# how to delete submodule in github that was added by accident

Tags: github, git-submodules, netlify

I'm trying to put on frontend project on Netlify, however, when i'm trying to deploy it i'm getting the below error message[image: error logs]

how can i get rid of the submodule?

see below my github page[image: github files]

Comment: Do you have a commit with .gitmodules? Your screenshot does not show it. And can you show the content of the .gitmodules file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not properly define what you want to delete.

But according to me, you want to delete one folder which you already deployed to netlify so what you can do is go to your VS Code and delete that particular folder from there and then again pushed the updated project to GitHub and then wait for some minutes it will reflect on your netlify.

If this won't work then reverts back.